# Therefore, once again, household guns correlate positively with additional shootings

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can I use *is directly proportional to*  in place of *correlate positively with*?

> Therefore, once again, household guns **correlate positively with** additional shootings.

Comment: What do you mean by "additional shootings"

Comment: The phrase *directly proportional to* does not mean the same thing as *correlate positively with*. If you're asking if they are equivalent, then the answer is no. But if this is your own writing, then you can say whatever you want to say.

Comment: It is from an essay titled              




In some countries, the number of shootings increase because many people have guns at home. To what extent do you agree or disagree? Give specific reasons and examples to support your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Correlation** means here that the two phenomena (A: some undefined statistics for possessing arms and B: number of shootings e. g. in the same region) are *somehow* connected.

**Positive correlation** means that the more A is expressed in numbers, the more the number B of shootings is for a region. So it can be *any* dependency where *B increases with A increasing* and such a dependency can be much more complicated than the suggested 'directly proportional'. For example, *'additional shootings'* in the original sentence could mean the statistical difference in number of shootings reported for regions where household guns are allowed, compared to regions where they are forbidden. So you *can't* use the much more specific *'directly proportional'* instead of *'positively correlated'*.